# Property is not being set in the proxy service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I try to set a property in the in sequence of a service and get it in the out sequence it is getting null always.
My proxy service,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="Simple_Stock_Quote_Service_Proxy"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
  <inSequence>
     <property name="quoteType" value="strong" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Type" expression="get-property('quoteType')"/>
     </log>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Quote Rating" expression="get-property('quoteType')"/>
     </log>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
  </endpoint>
  </target>
 <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope should be default or synapse to set a property in the insequence and access it in the outsequence.

```
scope="default"
```